# Is modulo slow in Java?

Tags: java, performance, modulo

I've been looking at the implementation of `ThreadLocal` in the JDK, out of curiosity, and I found this :

```
/**
 * Increment i modulo len.
 */
 private static int nextIndex(int i, int len) {
     return ((i + 1 < len) ? i + 1 : 0);
 }
```

It looks fairly obvious that this could be implemented with a simple `return (i + 1) % len`, but I think these guys know their stuff. Any idea why they did this ?

This code is highly oriented towards performance, with a custom map for holding thread-local mappings, weak references to help the GC being clever and so on, so I guess this is a matter of performance. Is modulo slow in Java ?

Comment: Well, this code will work even if `len` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Maybe this is why they did it like this?

Comment: Well not really because `i + 1` could overflow. I don't think it is any safer than a modulo although I don't know how the modulo behaves with overflows

Comment: Yes, precisely. Which means it will be less than `len`!

Comment: Ok I take your point, but this `len` is the number of buckets. They would run out of memory way before reaching the overflow

Comment: You are begging the question: was this done for performance? There's no evidence of that.

Comment: It is [this code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#312) you are referring to, right?

Comment: @Leo I have scanned this question a bit to quickly, let me take another look

Comment: @fge I'm looking at the Oracle JDK sources in Idea, but I think that yes, it is the same code as the Open JDK. I can see no obvious difference in the code

Comment: @Dici sorry, I've removed my comment, there was another one explaining that java does not generate the same code as assembly.

Comment: @Leo no problem, I did not even see that answer so I beat you at reading too fast

Comment: my feeling is that for % there may be some "worst case scenarios" where the interpreter can't choose a reasonable way to do the calculation (see http://blog.teamleadnet.com/2012/07/faster-division-and-modulo-operation.html)

Comment: @erickson no evidence, but this is the likliest reason isn't it ?

Comment: @Leo looks very plausible, a comment does say that the length MUST be a power of two, and there is indeed a dynamically resized array

Comment: anyway, upvoted, since it would be great to have an authoritative answer for this :-) (anyway -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754323/how-does-the-modulus-operator-in-java-function)

Comment: @Leo I'd be happy to accept your answer if you compile your discoveries. I actually feel bad about having jumped on SO without Googling more than 1 minute.  It's just that I like asking "unusual" questions here, answers are always interesting

Comment: Yes it's slow, there is a lot on Google about this.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that i comes always less then len ? (since for >= values the two expressions will return different results)

Comment: I am not sure how you think that both codes are equal. One will return 0 if you exceed len, the other will return a number between 0-len-1 no matter what number you provide.

Comment: @Bax I did not read all the code but I assume it is, given the comment. Same answer to you, Ata.

Comment: @Bax sounds like `i` is always a valid index in the array containing the buckets (array of size `len`).

Comment: it looks like @apangin provided a reasonable answer. You can accept his/hers :-)

Comment: @Leo I just did, I hadn't had the chance to read it yet. Thanks to you too

Comment: great question. one more place that modulo is replaced is when computing a bucket for `HashMap` internally; but there the main problem is that it's done against `hashCode`, that might be negative; and doing mod against a negative value will give you a negative value, and a negative index bucket...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`%` is avoided for performance reasons in this example.

`div`/`rem` operations are slower even on CPU architecture level; not only in Java. For example, minimum latency of `idiv` instruction on Haswell is about 10 cycles, but only 1 cycle for `add`.

Let's benchmark using [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class Modulo {
    @Param("16")
    int len;

    int i;

    @Benchmark
    public int baseline() {
        return i;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int conditional() {
        return i = (i + 1 < len) ? i + 1 : 0;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int mask() {
        return i = (i + 1) & (len - 1);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int mod() {
        return i = (i + 1) % len;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Benchmark           (len)  Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
Modulo.baseline        16  avgt   10  2,951 ± 0,038  ns/op
Modulo.conditional     16  avgt   10  3,517 ± 0,051  ns/op
Modulo.mask            16  avgt   10  3,765 ± 0,016  ns/op
Modulo.mod             16  avgt   10  9,125 ± 0,023  ns/op
```

As you can see, using `%` is ~2.6x slower than a conditional expression. JIT cannot optimize this automatically in the discussed `ThreadLocal` code, because the divisor (`table.length`) is variable.

Comment: I'll look at your answer in details tomorrow, I need some sleep right now :D Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

`mod` is **not** that slow in Java. It's implemented as the byte code instructions `irem` and `frem` for Integers and Floats respectively. The JIT does a good job of optimizing this.

In my benchmarks (see [article](https://lustforge.com/2016/05/08/modulo-operator-performance-impact/)), `irem` calls in JDK 1.8 take about **1 nanosecond**. That's pretty quick. `frem` calls are about 3x slower, so use integers where possible.

If you're using Natural Integers (e.g. array indexing) and a power of 2 Divisor (e.g. 8 thread locals), then you can use a bit twiddling trick to get a 20% performance gain.